# Wrapping BodySubscriber<InputStream> in GZIPInputStream leads to hang

Tags: java, gzipinputstream, java-http-client

I'm using the new `java.net.http` classes to handle asynchronous HTTP request+response exchanges, and I'm trying to find a way to have the BodySubscriber handle different encoding types such as gzip.

However, mapping a `BodySubsriber<InputStream>` so that the underlying stream is wrapped by a `GZIPInputStream` (when "Content-Encoding: gzip" is found in the response header) leads to a hang. No exceptions, just a total cessation of activity.

The code which maps the `BodySubscriber` looks like this:

```
private HttpResponse.BodySubscriber<InputStream> gzippedBodySubscriber(
        HttpResponse.ResponseInfo responseInfo) {
    return HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.mapping(
            HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.ofInputStream(),
            this::decodeGzipStream);
}

private InputStream decodeGzipStream(InputStream gzippedStream) {
    System.out.println("Entered decodeGzipStream method.");
    try {
        InputStream decodedStream = new GZIPInputStream(gzippedStream);
        System.out.println(
                "Created GZIPInputStream to handle response body stream.");
        return decodedStream;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException occurred while trying to create GZIPInputStream.");
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
}
```

Receiving an HTTP response which has "gzip" encoding leads to the console showing just this:

> Entered EncodedBodyHandler.apply method.
>   Entered decodeGzipStream method.

Nothing more is seen, so the line after the call to the `GZIPInputStream` constructor is never executed.

Does anyone know why this attempt to wrap the `InputStream` from a `BodySubscriber<InputStream>` in a `GZIPInputStream` is hanging?

Note: the equivalent method for unencoded (raw text) HTTP response bodies contains simply a call to `BodySubscribers.ofInputStream()` with no mapping, and this allows the response to be received and displayed without problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: [JDK-8217264](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217264) is fixed since JDK13

---

This is indeed a bug. I have logged [JDK-8217264](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217264). I can suggest two work-arounds:

### Workaround one

Do not use `BodySubscribers.mapping` - but transform the `InputStream` into a `GZIPInputStream` after getting the HttpResponse's body:

```
GZIPInputStream gzin = new GZIPInputStream(resp.getBody());
```

### Workaround two

Have the mapping function return a `Supplier<InputStream>` instead, taking care not to create the `GZIPInputStream` until `Supplier::get` is called

```
static final class ISS implements Supplier<InputStream> {
    final InputStream in;
    GZIPInputStream gz;
    ISS(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }
    public synchronized InputStream get() {
        if (gz == null) {
            try {
                gz = new GZIPInputStream(in);
            } catch (IOException t) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(t);
            }
        }
        return gz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: If someone knows how to format the code snippet above I'd be grateful. clicking on the {} button on the editor doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Seems that numbered list content doesn't play nice with code samples, so I've replaced your numbered list with headed sections. (Feel free to edit the headers to give them more descriptive names.) By the way, in the end I went with the `new GZIPInputStream(response.getBody())` workaround, as shown in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54064189/1515834).

Comment: Ah... Thanks for the info! I'll remember that for next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the exact same problem. I tried the example in the Javadoc of the `BodySubscribers.mapping` method. Same behavior, the application hangs without any errors.

Could be a bug, because this is an official example from the Javadoc.

```
  public static <W> BodySubscriber<W> asJSON(Class<W> targetType) {
     BodySubscriber<InputStream> upstream = BodySubscribers.ofInputStream();

     BodySubscriber<W> downstream = BodySubscribers.mapping(
           upstream,
           (InputStream is) -> {
               try (InputStream stream = is) {
                   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                   return objectMapper.readValue(stream, targetType);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
               }
           });
    return downstream;
 } }
```