# Does Java HTTP Client handle compression

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client

I tried to find any mention of handling of compression in new Java HTTP Client but failed. Is there a built-in configuration to handle for e.g. `gzip` or `deflate` compression?

I would expect to have a `BodyHandler` for e.g. something like this:

```
HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofGzipped(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
```

but I don't see any. I don't see any configuration in `HttpClient` either. Am I looking in the wrong place or was this intentionally not implemented and deferred to support libraries?

Comment: Have you tryed looking at the network log? If the client attaches the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip` it supports it. Note that there is often a difference of headers you get on the application side and on the network side of the http client.

Comment: Going through some documentation felt this might be related to the question [HPACK (Header Compression for HTTP/2) implementation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153353). Details over [Indexing Tables used in compression](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7541.html#indexing.tables) does mention both your sample compressions header in the [Appendix](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7541.html#static.table.definition).

Comment: @patrickf actually I added such header and was surprised that I got uncompressed content

Comment: @RomainHippeau how is it a duplicate? The question you linked is about apache http client and mine is about Java http client (the one embedded in Java 11), notice the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, gzip/deflate compression are not handled by default. You would have to implement that in your application code if you need it - e.g. by providing a customized `BodySubscriber` to handle it. Alternatively - you may want to have a look at whether some of the reactive stream libraries out there offer such a feature, in which case you might be able to pipe that in by using one of the `BodyHandlers.fromSubscriber​(Flow.Subscriber<? super List<ByteBuffer>> subscriber)` or `BodyHandlers.ofPublisher()` methods.

Comment: It's a pity, considering that there is already a GzipInput/OutputStream in the standard library.

Comment: Right. Though using Input/OutputStream would force you back to synchronous mode when pulling the request bytes. Maybe you could use `BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(..)` and `BodySubscribers.ofInputStream()` with some combination of the PipedInput/OutputStream and GzipInput/OutputStream too - but then you'd still have to pull the request bytes.

Comment: I did try the `BodySubscriber` approach (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379087/wrapping-bodysubscriberinputstream-in-gzipinputstream-leads-to-hang)) but it led to a total hang. So instead I went with the less glamorous approach which I've described in my answer to @KrzysztofKrasoń and that works fine. Frustrating, though.

Comment: Is there an example to refer to using this approach while writing custom BodyHandler?

Answer (score 18):

I was also surprised that the new `java.net.http` framework doesn't handle this automatically, but the following works for me to handle HTTP responses which are received as an `InputStream` and are either uncompressed or compressed with gzip:

```
public static InputStream getDecodedInputStream(
        HttpResponse<InputStream> httpResponse) {
    String encoding = determineContentEncoding(httpResponse);
    try {
        switch (encoding) {
            case "":
                return httpResponse.body();
            case "gzip":
                return new GZIPInputStream(httpResponse.body());
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        "Unexpected Content-Encoding: " + encoding);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
    }
}

public static String determineContentEncoding(
        HttpResponse<?> httpResponse) {
    return httpResponse.headers().firstValue("Content-Encoding").orElse("");
}
```

Note that I've not added support for the "deflate" type (because I don't currently need it, and the more I read about "deflate" the more of a mess it sounded). But I believe you can easily support "deflate" by adding a check to the above switch block and wrapping the `httpResponse.body()` in an `InflaterInputStream`.

Comment: It's a good answer, however at least once I met a website which returned Content-Encoding : gzip, but actually there was no gzip encoding involved in the body. And this kind of code would throw an exception. To deal with it I used HttpResponse<byte[]> using BodyHandlers.ofByteArray() and if Content-Encoding is set to gzip trying to new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) and if I get the exception, simply use that byte[] as raw data. It's less efficient, but for me it was critical, since I have had no control over the website with the wrong encoding, but needed to use it.

Comment: @Kivan I had this issue at some point too, I remember I developed a workaround to discover the actual payload content using a `java.io.PushbackInputStream`, so it's easy to check the [Gzip payload header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) (`1F 8B 08`), pushback and either wrap in `GZIPINputStream` or not.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Methanol](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/). It has [decompressing](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/decompression/) `BodyHandler` implementations, with out-of-the-box support for `gzip` & `deflate`. There's also a [module](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/brotli/) for brotli.

```java
var response = client.send(request, MoreBodyHandlers.decoding(BodyHandlers.ofString()));
```

Note that you can use any `BodyHandler` you want. `MoreBodyHandlers::decoding` makes it seem to your handler like the response was never compressed! It takes care of the `Content-Encoding` header and all.

Better yet, you can use Methanol's own `HttpClient`, which does transparent decompression after adding the appropriate `Accept-Encoding` to your requests.

```java
var client = Methanol.create();
var request = MutableRequest.GET("https://example.com");
var response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString()); // The response is transparently decompressed
```

Comment: Methanol looks quite interesting! Thank you for recommending it.