# HttpClient read response body in java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

I created a rest API for login using Spring Boot, but in client(Java) I am not able to see response body.

```
   HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:9091/student/" + response))
                .GET()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response1 =
                client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println("res: " + response1.body());
```

My function from controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RequestPath.GET_STUDENT_BY_ID, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getById(@PathVariable UUID id){
    StudentEntity res = studentService.findById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(res);
}
```

I tested my API using postman and I am able to  see the response body in json format.

Is there another way to get the response body using Java Http client?

Comment: response is an uuid from the data base. I use that to collect all information for that student. UUID is FK in student table

Comment: http://localhost:9091/student/e577cf18-53bb-4e4e-bce2-b543f1d51f85 -> request

Comment: Please specify which HttpClient are you are using with a full import statement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using HttpClient( superclass of `CloseableHttpClient`)

> HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

you can use `CloseableHttpClient` which is Closeable.

> CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

Send Request:

```
        Map<String, String> requestHeader = Maps.newHashMap();
       requestHeader.put(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");


        /* OPTIONAL: you can set you auth here.*/
        requestHeader.put(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        get.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType.getDescription());
        for (String key : requestHeader.keySet()) {
            get.addHeader(key, requestHeader.get(key));
        }
        response = client.execute(get);
```

Read Response:

```
    StringBuilder     builder = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream       is      = null;
    InputStreamReader isr     = null;
    BufferedReader    br      = null;

      try {
        is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw (e);
    }
String responseString = builder.toString();
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope it might help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to get response body in postman, you could get that in any client.

You can use the following link to generate code snippet directly from postman, which will give you desired response body.
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Hope, I was able to solve your issue.

Comment: Not work, because i dont have that classes and not find dependency for them. I updated my cod but not work

Comment: Use Maven to get the dependencies or you could also download the required jar files and add them to your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your endpoint is returning gzip'd content. e.g using PostMan do you see a header like `Content-Encoding: gzip`? If so, that's likely the issue. `java.net.http.HttpClient` does not handle gzip for you automatically (unlike many other clients). See [Does Java HTTP Client handle compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502626/does-java-http-client-handle-compression) for some solutions for handling compressed responses.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting "Content-Type" on the request??? Are you sure that this shouldn't be "Accept"? It's not unlikely that fixing the request header fields will resolve your issue.